# How can I read this line in the C language

Tags: c, string, text, file-io

I am writing in C and I am trying to read this line:

```
phillip.allen@enron.com -> tim.belden@enron.com at 989883540
```

I want 4 separate strings:

```
sender_username: phillip.allen
sender_hostname: enron.com
receiver_username: tim.belden
receiver_hostname: enron.c
```

I want to get rid of the "at 989883540" part of the text.

I am using this conversion:

```
"%49[^@ ]@%49s -> %49[^@ ]@%49s"
```

I seem to get the sender username and hostname, so the first part of the email before the -> symbol, but I cannot read the receiver part of tim.belden part.

Comment: Hey! That's the Enron email corpus!

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `%49s` with `%49[^ ]` should do the trick:

```
"%49[^@]@%49[^ ] -> %49[^@]@%49[^ ]"
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/a7a0x0).

Comment: Wow that actually worked thanks. Now I have a few questions. Why do you not include the %s 4 times as the conversion specifiers? How does it know what to look for?

Comment: @user2817240 `%49[^@]` and `%49[^ ]` are valid conversion specifiers, `scanf` knows to look for `@` first, then stop, then consume the `@`, then consume everything up to the following space, and so on.

Comment: Alright is there a manual or somewhere where I can read up on this?

Comment: @user2817240 [Absolutely!](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) There's also [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) with a convenient table. The second site is for C++, but the formats are the same.

Comment: @user2817240 You are welcome. If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would indicate to other site visitors that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.